# How can I implement this jQuery click event that it works properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click the button, then a menu is showing up with a rotation animation and it closes again, when i click the button again but i need to click the button three times to show up the menu again.
do you know how to fix that?

```
var angleStart = -360;

// jquery rotate animation
function rotate(li,d) {
    $({d:angleStart}).animate({d:d}, {
        step: function(now) {
            $(li)
               .css({ transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)' })
               .find('label')
                  .css({ transform: 'rotate('+(-now)+'deg)' });
        }, duration: 0
    });
}

// show / hide the options
function toggleOptions(s) {
    $( 'button' ).click(function() {
        $(s).toggleClass('open');
        var li = $(s).find('li');
        var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180/(li.length-1) : 360/li.length;
        for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
            var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i*deg)-90 : i*deg;
            $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i],d) : rotate(li[i],angleStart);
        }
    });
}

$( 'button' ).click(function() {
    $('.selector button').click(function(e) {
        toggleOptions($(this).parent());
    });
});

setTimeout(function() { toggleOptions('.selector'); }, 100);
```

Comment: The issue is due to the nested `click` handlers. However it's hard to show you what the correct logic would be without seeing the HTML

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can see a running example of what you are experiencing.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan says, We can't know for sure what the logic would be, but a easy guess would be something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/as5fd06d/

Comment: I tried working out the solution from the answer and it worked a single time but now only the button shows up but the animation isn't after I click the button. https://jsfiddle.net/5qsww27j/#&togetherjs=fDmGdDMIHo

Answer (score 0):

- Take the button which shows stuff out of `.selector` container, otherwise the nested click will conflict since it's impacting any generic buttons inside `.selector` (`$('.selector button').click()`)
- With that should work, however I'd also clean up/comment those nested clicks since they are unnecessary.

Example:

```
/*$('.selector button').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});*/
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var angleStart = -360;

// jquery rotate animation
function rotate(li, d) {
  $({
    d: angleStart
  }).animate({
    d: d
  }, {
    step: function(now) {
      $(li)
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        })
        .find('label')
        .css({
          transform: 'rotate(' + (-now) + 'deg)'
        });
    },
    duration: 0
  });
}

// show / hide the options
function toggleOptions(s) {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(s).toggleClass('open');
    var li = $(s).find('li');
    var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180 / (li.length - 1) : 360 / li.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i * deg) - 90 : i * deg;
      $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i], d) : rotate(li[i], angleStart);
    }
  });
}

//This is unnecessary, at least for the code you've shared.
/*$('.selector button').click(function(e) {
  toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});*/


setTimeout(function() {
  toggleOptions('.selector');
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selector'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id='1' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='1'>Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='2' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='2'>Option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='3' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='3'>Option 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='4' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='4'>Option 4</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Move this button out of .selector or impact the nested displayed stuff with a class instead of .selector button -->
<button>show stuff</button>
```

Comment: Lol, it worked for a short time and now the button is showing up, when i click nothing happens. what have i done wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/5qsww27j/#&togetherjs=fDmGdDMIHo

Comment: You are missing a dot on `$('button1')`, should be `$('.button1')`.

Comment: Great David, if it helped you please consider marking the answer correct, thank you, regards.